# copy android failed! Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor, moodle-mobile

i am work on windows using android studio
i try setting up development environment for the moodle app
Specifically for android platform .
i follow the instructions from moodle app site
and When I reach the running step
and execute "npx cap run android" command
Everything seems fine Except for two messages that appear in the logs

- × copy android - failed!
  [error] Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat
  'C:\Users\user\Desktop\moodleapp-main\cordova-plugin-moodleapp\www\index.js'
- × update android - failed!
  [error] Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat
  'C:\Users\user\Desktop\moodleapp-main\cordova-plugin-moodleapp\www\index.js'

here's the full log :

> PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\moodleapp-main> npx cap run android
> Copying web assets from www to android\app\src\main\assets\public in 6.21s
> Creating capacitor.config.json in android\app\src\main\assets in 1.66ms
> copy android [info] Found 28 Cordova plugins for android:
> @moodlehq/cordova-plugin-advanced-http@3.3.1-moodle.1
> @moodlehq/cordova-plugin-camera@6.0.0-moodle.2
> @moodlehq/cordova-plugin-file-transfer@1.7.1-moodle.5
> @moodlehq/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@5.0.0-moodle.3
> @moodlehq/cordova-plugin-intent@2.2.0-moodle.2
> @moodlehq/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@5.0.0-moodle.3
> @moodlehq/cordova-plugin-local-notification@0.9.0-moodle.11
> @moodlehq/cordova-plugin-qrscanner@3.0.1-moodle.5
> @moodlehq/cordova-plugin-statusbar@4.0.0-moodle.3
> @moodlehq/cordova-plugin-zip@3.1.0-moodle.1
> @moodlehq/phonegap-plugin-push@4.0.0-moodle.7
> cordova-clipboard@1.3.0
> cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter@1.1.3
> cordova-plugin-badge@0.8.9
> cordova-plugin-chooser@1.3.2
> cordova-plugin-customurlscheme@5.0.2
> cordova-plugin-device@2.1.0
> cordova-plugin-file@6.0.2
> cordova-plugin-file-opener2@4.0.0
> cordova-plugin-geolocation@5.0.0
> cordova-plugin-media-capture@3.0.3
> cordova-plugin-network-information@3.0.0
> cordova-plugin-prevent-override@1.0.1
> cordova-plugin-screen-orientation@3.0.4
> cordova-sqlite-storage@6.1.0
> cordova.plugins.diagnostic@7.1.4
> es6-promise-plugin@4.2.2
> cordova-plugin-moodleapp@0.0.0
> copy android - failed!
> [error] Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat
> 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\moodleapp-main\cordova-plugin-moodleapp\www\index.js'
> Updating Android plugins in 98.17ms
> update android [info] Found 28 Cordova plugins for android:
> @moodlehq/cordova-plugin-advanced-http@3.3.1-moodle.1
> @moodlehq/cordova-plugin-camera@6.0.0-moodle.2
> @moodlehq/cordova-plugin-file-transfer@1.7.1-moodle.5
> @moodlehq/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@5.0.0-moodle.3
> @moodlehq/cordova-plugin-intent@2.2.0-moodle.2
> @moodlehq/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@5.0.0-moodle.3
> @moodlehq/cordova-plugin-local-notification@0.9.0-moodle.11
> @moodlehq/cordova-plugin-qrscanner@3.0.1-moodle.5
> @moodlehq/cordova-plugin-statusbar@4.0.0-moodle.3
> @moodlehq/cordova-plugin-zip@3.1.0-moodle.1
> @moodlehq/phonegap-plugin-push@4.0.0-moodle.7
> cordova-clipboard@1.3.0
> cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter@1.1.3
> cordova-plugin-badge@0.8.9
> cordova-plugin-chooser@1.3.2
> cordova-plugin-customurlscheme@5.0.2
> cordova-plugin-device@2.1.0
> cordova-plugin-file@6.0.2
> cordova-plugin-file-opener2@4.0.0
> cordova-plugin-geolocation@5.0.0
> cordova-plugin-media-capture@3.0.3
> cordova-plugin-network-information@3.0.0
> cordova-plugin-prevent-override@1.0.1
> cordova-plugin-screen-orientation@3.0.4
> cordova-sqlite-storage@6.1.0
> cordova.plugins.diagnostic@7.1.4
> es6-promise-plugin@4.2.2
> cordova-plugin-moodleapp@0.0.0
> update android - failed!
> [error] Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat
> 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\moodleapp-main\cordova-plugin-moodleapp\www\index.js'